# How to upload file in mysql using PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, input

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    include ('navbar.php');
?>
<form class = "container m-5" method = "POST" action = "upload.php" encytype = "multipart/form-data">
<input class = "form-control w-25" type = "file" name = "file">
<button class = "btn" type = "submit" name = "Upload">Upload</button>
</form>

<?php
include'connect.php';
$statusMsg = '';

// File upload path
$targetDir = "image";
$fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
$fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
    // Allow certain file formats
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','pdf');
    if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
        // Upload file to server
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){
            // Insert image file name into database
            $insert = $db->query("INSERT into userid (FileName) VALUES ('".$fileName."'");
            if($insert){
                $statusMsg = "The file ".$fileName. " has been uploaded successfully.";
            }else{
                $statusMsg = "File upload failed, please try again.";
            } 
        }else{
            $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }else{
        $statusMsg = 'Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, & PDF files are allowed to upload.';
    }
}else{
    $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.'; 
}

// Display status message
echo $statusMsg;
?>
```

The only message that I received is this

> Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\upload.php on
> line 15 Please select a file to upload.

And nothing shows in my database

Comment: You're fetching `$fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];` before checking if it exists. Just move those lines inside your `if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"]))` instead. And change `isset($_POST["submit"])` to `isset($_POST["Upload"])` (which is the name of the submit button)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson good catch on the name of the submit button, didn't even see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

you have 2 typo in your code.

1. form attribute should be `enctype` not `encytype`.
2. change submit button name like `Upload`.
3. Change the input type file name to some other name like `filename`

   ```
    <form class = "container m-5" method = "POST" action = "upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input class = "form-control w-25" type = "file" name = "filename">
    <button class = "btn" type = "submit" name = "Upload">Upload</button>
    </form>

    <?php
    include'connect.php';
    $statusMsg = '';

    // File upload path

    if(isset($_POST["Upload"]) && !empty($_FILES["filename"]["name"])){
        $targetDir = "image/";
        $fileName = $_FILES["filename"]["name"];
        $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
        $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        // Allow certain file formats
        $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','pdf');
        if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
            // Upload file to server
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){
                // Insert image file name into database
                $insert = $db->query("INSERT into userid (FileName) VALUES ('".$fileName."'");
                if($insert){
                    $statusMsg = "The file ".$fileName. " has been uploaded successfully.";
                }else{
                    $statusMsg = "File upload failed, please try again.";
                } 
            }else{
                $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }else{
            $statusMsg = 'Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, & PDF files are allowed to upload.';
        }
    }else{
        $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.'; 
    }

    // Display status message
    echo $statusMsg;
    ?>
   ```

Comment: "Please select a file to upload." is what is visible when i tried to upload a file nothing happens to my database and the message never change.

Comment: Did you replace with my code?

Comment: yup i read it carefully and copy it. BTW it worked now but the thing is the file is not saving in my database.

Comment: please check insert query and DB connection. I dont know your table stucture and field names.

Comment: yep it's working now thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

First check if the file *is set*:

```
if(isset($_FILES["file"])) {
    include'connect.php';
    $statusMsg = '';

    // File upload path
    $targetDir = "image";
    // ...
}
```

You seem to also be missing a `/` here

```
$targetDir = "image/";   // <-- here
$targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
```

Since you are doing this

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
```

you can then move the php code that is under the HTML inside the `if` statement in which case you don't need to check if the file *is set* before hand since `empty()` also covers `isset()`:

```
if(isset($_POST["Upload"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
    include'connect.php';
    $statusMsg = '';

    // File upload path
    $targetDir = "image/";
    $fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
    $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // Allow certain file formats
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','pdf');
    
    //...
}
```

**Note:** as pointed out in the comments by @MagnusEriksson, your button's name is `Upload` so that is what you should be checking for in your `isset()` function.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: db in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\upload.php on line 29

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\upload.php:29 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\upload.php on line 29

i got this error i already the $insert outside my if statement